# Can I use the Eberron adventures as a short adventure path?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, published-adventures, eberron, adventure-path

What level are the various *Eberron* adventures WotC put out for, and what level will my players most likely wind up after each one? Neither the WotC site or wikipedia list what level range all of them are for, and they don't list what level you end on.

I'm asking as I'd like to run them as a shortened adventure path, but I'm not sure if you finish each at the right level to start the next one.

Comment: It looks like [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Eberron_modules_and_sourcebooks#Adventures) has updated, at least for the 5 after the first one.  I would assume that the first is for levels 1-3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Yes

Shamelessly stealing from wikipedia produces:

### Path 1

- *Shadows of the Last War* (July 2004, ISBN 0-7869-3276-7). This adventure is designed as a sequel to *The Forgotten Forge* from the core campaign setting, but can be run on its own.

  - [Errata](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCQQFjAA&url=http://wizards.custhelp.com/ci/fattach/get/33628/&ei=ssDJToGrFKzXiAKlmby3CA&usg=AFQjCNG39TabiCAdN6tRs370KbTUQdYsYQ&sig2=d9s2XYk4zlMwPfbxkaf4oQ)
- *Whispers of the Vampire's Blade* (September 2004, ISBN 0-7869-3510-3) This adventure is designed as follow on adventure to *Shadows of the Last War* for 4th-level heroes, but it can be run on its own. It takes them across the continent of Khorvaire with action-packed overland and aerial travel.
- *Grasp of the Emerald Claw* (January 2005, ISBN 0-7869-3652-5) This adventure is designed as a sequel to *Whispers of the Vampire's Blade* for 6th-level heroes, but can be run on its own.

### Stand Alone

- *Voyage of the Golden Dragon* (April 2006, ISBN 0-7869-3907-9) This adventure is designed as a stand-alone adventure for 7th-level heroes focusing on the first voyage of a massive airship.

### Path 2

- *Eyes of the Lich Queen* (April 2007, ISBN 9780786943197). This super-adventure is for levels 5-10, involves dragons, the *Blood of Vol*, and a curse tied to *The Draconic Prophecy*.

There doesn't seem to be any published or unofficial updates to those resources other than that listed.

It's probably best to run path 1, then run path 2 slightly leveled. It should be easy enough to just add more supporting characters to the fights to represent the added difficulty.

Comment: So the answer would rather be "Kinda" Since you could use the first 4, but then you'd be too high level for Eyes of the Lich Queen, and Seekers of the Ashen Crown is 4e. Thanks. I'll award you the 50 rep as soon as it lets me, provided no one else somehow makes a better answer.

Comment: Fixed. Thanks. And yes, this isn't an answer that should earn the bounty.

Comment: I'm not sure what other answer there could be though- Either I missed those on Wikipedia or they added them after I looked. Why don't you edit yours to be more detailed and discuss those problems to make it worthy?

Comment: Sheer laziness? And I want someone else to get the +50 points :) But yeah, the proper answer would have access to these sources and detail changes to the sources to make them turn into an adventure path. Spent some time looking for a site that did it, but came up dry.

Comment: Ok, I'll only give you the +50 in a few days then, since it expires at some point.